# Ubuntu 11.10 disconnects me from internet (cable)

Tags: 11.10, networking, ethernet, offline

I'm connected to the Internet via router (wired) and Ubuntu disconnects me from it. I have to manually disconnect from my network (via panel in top-right corner) and connect again. I don't know why. Can someone help me? I will give any information that will be needed.

P.S. On Windows 7 everything is OK, so it isn't the fault of the network card.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*You haven't given enough details to accurately diagnose ..*

(the obvious) Check your settings.

(Network Icon) >> Edit Connections

It should look like:

[image]

Comment: I have exactly what you have.

Comment: **Brand, model of router?**  Maybe someone else has seen something similar.